# famo.us support native app or not

Tags: javascript, html, css, famo.us

Is Famo.us(A new mobile application development framework) support native application,as I doesn't want my app browser based.I have read many doc's related to the same but i did'nt get anything regarding native app.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think Cordova(or its commercial distribution PhoneGap) is what you need. It basically packages your HTML/JS/CSS files and a WebView into a native app. Just follow the instructions on the website http://cordova.apache.org/ to setup cordova.

When it comes to Famo.us, the simplest workflow I get is to use grunt to directly compile files to the `www/` folder of the cordova project. Then you're good to go.

Note1: Cordova uses an old version of `WebView` on Android. If performance is your concern, use [CROSSWALK](https://crosswalk-project.org/) with Cordova following the instruction [here](https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application). Basically it replaces the old `WebView` with a newer version so that your native-web-app has better performance on Android.

Note2: Famo.us is working on their own wrapper, which should do the work above automatically and faster. This should be released soon.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.  A couple notes:(1) grunt build isn't strictly required as you can directly edit files in www folder. (2) famo.us is working on a version of cordova that includes updated WebKit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is stackoverflow appropriate, but it presumably can work inside a Webview wrapper, which essentially still works like a browser, but one can save the app to their device. No idea how well it will work.

Famo.us is pretty young, so i'm sure as the library matures, solutions around mobile apps will start to emerge.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of interest. This was just announced in the latest Famo.us newsletter:

> 1. At the meetup: The Famo.us Wrapper We are working on providing developers the very best solution for wrapping for each OS. For
>      Android, we are offering a pluggable webview (Chrome 35) that enables
>      you to create a stable, fast webview regardless of the OS or internal
>      webview on an Android device. We are building this solution in
>      collaboration with Intel. For iOS, Microsoft, Kindle, and Firefox, we
>      are building an optimized solution in collaboration with Adobe. ALL
>      wrapped solutions and services that we are building are based on
>      Cordova.

Should be released in the near future.

[Full newsletter here](http://us5.campaign-archive1.com/?u=4656ba2b0a364690c8530bc1e&id=c3d17f40a5&e=a8d69bc1c6&utm_content=bufferd1e66&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)

Answer (score 0):

I used intel XDK to create the "native" wrapper for my test app. Worked extremely well.